# Mongodb javascript query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am querying a mongo database using a javascript file. I have a for loop and I am adding to myArray using myArray.push(value).

My problem is when I run the script in Robomongo I get 2 outputs - the length of the array(which I don't want) and the print statements(I want).

Is there anyway to prevent the script from outputting the length of the array - is there another function I should be using other than .push???

Here is some of the script:

```
var myArray = [];
var result = jobData['result'];

for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    var collection = result[i].Tolerances;
    for(var j = 0; j < collection.length; j++){
        var cur = collection[j];
        myArray.push(cur);      // I do not want this value outputted
    }
}
for(var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++){
    var value = myArray[x];
    print("Currency From: "+value.FromCurrency+";Currency To: "+value.ToCurrency+";Tolerance: "+value.TolerancePercentage+");
};
```

If there is more detail required just let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** and **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** methods to construct the new array without logging the length of the new array. The following example demonstrates how to use these two methods in your case:

```
var jobData = {
    result: [
        { Tolerances: ["foo", "bar"] },
        { Tolerances: ["abc", "def"] },
        { Tolerances: ["123", "456"] }
    ]
};
var myArray = [];
var result = jobData['result'];  

var tolerances = result.map(function (r){
    return r.Tolerances;    
});

myArray = tolerances.reduce(function (a, b){
    return a.concat(b);
});

printjson(myArray);
// prints ["foo","bar","abc","def","123","456"]
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var jobData = {
 result: [
  { Tolerances: ["foo", "bar"] },
  { Tolerances: ["abc", "def"] },
  { Tolerances: ["123", "456"] }
 ]
}
var myArray = [];
var result = jobData['result'];


var tolerances = result.map(function (r){
 return r.Tolerances; 
})

myArray = tolerances.reduce(function (a, b){
 return a.concat(b);
})

pre.innerHTML = "myArray: " + JSON.stringify(myArray, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```